# setAttribute works but .attr() and .data() is failing to set data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a custom drop down i have successfully did it. But the doubt is why am i not able to set the data like `x.data('name','value')` or `x.attr('data-name','value')`. `x.setAttribute('data-name','value')` is working. I get the errors:

> x.data is not a function
>   x.attr is not a function

What am I doing wrong here? Please correct me as I'm still learning.

This is my code :

```
$(document).on('click','li.cus-dropdown-option',function(e){
    var x = $(this).parent().prev().children()[0];
    x.innerHTML = $(this).data("option-desc");
    x.setAttribute('data-selected-desc', $(this).data("option-desc"));
    x.setAttribute('data-selected-val', $(this).data("option-value"));
```

Comment: Define "not able to set the data?" What error(s) do you get? What does the DOM end up looking like?

Comment: Setting using `data()` will not appear in the DOM, as it is kept in jQuery's internal cache. It would still be accessible using the getter of `data()`. Setting using `attr()` is slower, should still work, and should be visible in the DOM. What is the specific reason you think neither of them is working?

Comment: I get `x.data is not a function` or `x.attr is not a function`

Comment: `x` is not a jquery object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you receive are because you are retrieving the DOMElement from the jQuery object by using `[0]`. If your intention is to retrieve the first element from the matched set you should use `first()`. Then you receive back a jQuery object which you can then call `data()` on. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','li.cus-dropdown-option', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().prev().children().first()
        .html($(this).data("option-desc"))
        .data({
            'selected-desc', $(this).data("option-desc"),
            'selected-val', $(this).data("option-value")
        });
});
```

Comment: just found that `.eq(0)` returns a jQuery object by index as well :)

Comment: It does indeed. There is also the `:eq(n)` selector too.